# Getting query string parameter value having '&' in it in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am passing url as follows ...

```
Response.Redirect("~/all-media/books/?serachtext=on&off");
```

where serachtext is the only parameter. So, when I access this parameter as follows, it gives me only "on" as value.

```
Request.QueryString["searchtext"]
```

So, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work. The ampersand needs to be URL encoded.

The URL encoded value for an ampersand is `%26`. SO you can do either:

a)

```
Response.Redirect("~/all-media/books/?serachtext=on%26off");
```

or b)

```
Response.Redirect("~/all-media/books/?serachtext=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("on&off"));
```

Comment: I encoded the url which replaces & with %26 but when I try to access this parameter by Request.QueryString["serachtext"] it gives only "on"

Comment: @hetalgala You're doing something incorrectly then. I just tried it and it works perfectly. You'll have to show us what you're doing.

Comment: did you try Request.QueryString["serachtext"]?

Comment: also wanted to add that url becomes, ~/all-media/books/?serachtext=on+%26+off .. as we have url rewrite rule to replace space with +

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the value that you put in the query string:

```
Response.Redirect("~/all-media/books/?searchtext=" + Server.UrlEncode("on&off"));
```

Or do it manually:

```
Response.Redirect("~/all-media/books/?searchtext=on%26off");
```

Comment: did the same but after redirection, when I want to access value as Request.QueryString["serachtext"] it breaks near &.. i.e. it returns "on" only..

Comment: @hetalgala: Then something went wrong when you updated the code. Note also that you are mixing `searchtext` and `serachtext`, so check the spelling.

Comment: spelling is correct.. wanted to add that url becomes, ~/all-media/books/?serachtext=on+%26+off .. as we have url rewrite rule to replace space with +

Comment: can you give me some solution?

Comment: @hetalgala: Where do the spaces come from? An URL should not contain spaces at all, as that it not a valid character in an URL according to the standard.

Comment: space come from user entered input. i.e. if user searach with text "on & off" .. but by using url re-write rules we convert space to + sign. so in url I get encoded string as "on+%26+off".. now want actual value from this string.. so how can I do that?

Comment: @hetalgala: The spaces and the ampersand are correctly encoded, so when you get the query string in the request you will get the string `"on & off"`.

Comment: but it does not happen that way. When I access Request.QueryString["serachtext"], it only return "on ".. what could be the issue?

Comment: one more thing I observed is this works fine in localhost but not on production server...

Comment: @hetalgala: That sounds more like a problem with the rewrite. Using a rewrite rule to correct the encoding of the data sounds like a shaky solution to start with, the value should preferrably be encoded correctly before it ends up in the URL to start with.

Comment: yes.. u are right.. I also feel that I have to play with url rewrite/redirect rules somewhere to solve the issue